# Error: Underlying stream not writable when trying to download file from remote server to node server

Tags: linux, node.js, download, copy, scp

I am trying to download a file from a remote linux server (from directory /home/dataFiles/test.txt) into node server (to directory H:/dataDirOnNodeServer) using the node-scp2 module. In order to do so I run the following:

```
client.scp('linuxUsername:linuxPassword@linuxserverName:/home/dataFiles/test.txt', 'H:/dataDirOnNodeServer', function(err) {
     console.log(err);
})
```

I get an error: Error: Underlying stream not writable

I would really appreciate it if you can help me with this or if you can advise how to do it differently to make it work.

Comment: This means that `H:/dataDirOnNodeServer` doesn't exist. Are you sure it does?

Comment: Also, if it's a directory you are providing, it should end with a `/`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I verified the path is there on my windows machine which is my ndoe server. Also I added / at the end but i get the same error. I am not sure what I am missing

Comment: do i have the order of the arguments right?

Comment: Arguments look correct. Can you replace the `H:..` with `./`

Comment: did try that too, originally it was ./ and I got this error so I tried H:/ instead but i get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110175/discussion-between-rahat-mahbub-and-nat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this! The issue was that I was calling this client within a success of another client, therefore the file was using the same instance to perform the copy. To fix this I changed the scp library code  loacted in scp2/lib/scp.js as follows:

```
-var client = require('./client');
+var Client = require('./client').Client;
+var client = new Client();
```

(First line was removed and the two lines below were added), this way every time a new instance is called. This also solved an issue of stack overflow I was getting prior this.